# Using find method that require only key in boost splay_set

Tags: boost

The find method of `boost::splay_set` that require only the key accepts an argument of type `KeyValueCompare` to compare objects with the key. To be able to use this, we need to supply two methods of the form:

```
struct KeyValCompare {
  inline bool operator() (const std::int64_t key, const MyType& val) const {
     //TODO:
  }

  inline bool operator() (const MyType& val, const std::int64_t key) const {
     //TODO:
  }
};
```

However there is no mention in the documentation about how to implement these. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the comparator would be so complicated. The set just stores elements of MyType, so you need to define a strict weak total ordering on them:

```
struct Comparator {
    bool operator()(MyType const& a, MyType const& b) const;
};
```

Indeed, the default comparer is `std::less<MyType>`

E.g. to sort

```
class MyType : public splay_set_base_hook<>
{
    int int_;
  public:
    MyType(int i) :  int_(i) {}

    int getValue() const { return int_; }
};
```

By the value, after reversing the digits (e.g. "431" before "322" because `134<223`):

```
struct CompareReversed {

    bool operator()(MyType const& a, MyType const& b) const {
        return reversed(a.getValue()) < reversed(b.getValue());
    }

  private:

    static int reversed(int i)
    {
        auto s = std::to_string(i);
        std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        return boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
    }
};
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5450ad41ccb7ddb)**:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/splay_set.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class MyType : public splay_set_base_hook<>
{
    int int_;

  public:
    MyType(int i) :  int_(i)
    {}

    // default ordering
    friend bool operator<  (const MyType &a, const MyType &b) {  return a.int_ <  b.int_;  }
    friend bool operator>  (const MyType &a, const MyType &b) {  return a.int_ >  b.int_;  }
    friend bool operator== (const MyType &a, const MyType &b) {  return a.int_ == b.int_;  }

    int getValue() const { return int_; }
};

struct CompareReversed {

    bool operator()(MyType const& a, MyType const& b) const {
        return reversed(a.getValue()) < reversed(b.getValue());
    }

  private:

    static int reversed(int i)
    {
        auto s = std::to_string(i);
        std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        return boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //typedef splay_set<MyType, compare<std::less<MyType> > > Set;
    typedef splay_set<MyType, compare<CompareReversed> > Set;

    std::vector<MyType> v { 24, 42, 123, 321 };

    Set set;
    set.insert(v[0]);
    set.insert(v[1]);
    set.insert(v[2]);
    set.insert(v[3]);

    for (auto& el : set)
    {
        std::cout << el.getValue() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << set.count(24) << "\n"; // 1
    std::cout << set.count(25) << "\n"; // 0
    std::cout << set.count(42) << "\n"; // 1
}
```

If you want to suppor mixed type comparisons, just supply the overloads, obviously:

```
struct CompareReversed {

    bool operator()(MyType const& a, MyType const& b) const {
        return reversed(a.getValue()) < reversed(b.getValue());
    }

    bool operator()(MyType const& a, int b) const {
        return reversed(a.getValue()) < reversed(b);
    }

    bool operator()(int a, MyType const& b) const {
        return reversed(a) < reversed(b.getValue());
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This part is done already. My question is how to implement the two operators that is required when you search using a key, not a value. In my case, creating the value type for the search is expensive, so I want to just use the key to search. This is supported in a different version of a find which takes the key type and a comparison object which has the two function operators defined with two signatures. I have no idea what to put on those two functions.

Comment: You just implement it as a polymorphic comparator. This is not a specific feature for splay sets (standard library has exactly the same capabilities, e.g. when you pass a comparator to `std::find`, std::lower_bound`, `std::equal_range`). **Updated the answer**

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here:
http://boost.cowic.de/rc/pdf/intrusive.pdf

they should return true if key (or key from the value) of lhs is less than the key (or key from the value) of rhs.

Comment: This is the [total weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sehe for the support. 
That is exactly what I am doing there. But please have a look at following sample code which fails.

```
#include <boost/intrusive/splay_set.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace boost::intrusive;

class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass(const std::int64_t& k)
        : key(k) {
    }
    std::int64_t key;

    splay_set_member_hook<> member_hook_;

    friend bool operator <(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
      return lhs.key < rhs.key;
    }

    friend bool operator >(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
      return lhs.key > rhs.key;
    }

    friend bool operator ==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
      return lhs.key == rhs.key;
    }
};

struct KeyValCompare {
    inline bool operator()(const std::int64_t key, const MyClass& val) const {
      return key < val.key;
    }

    inline bool operator()(const MyClass& val, const std::int64_t key) const {
      return val.key < key;
    }
};

typedef member_hook<MyClass, splay_set_member_hook<>, &MyClass::member_hook_> MemberOption;

typedef splay_set<MyClass, MemberOption, compare<std::greater<MyClass> > > MyClassObjectsType;

TEST(MyClass, test) {
  MyClassObjectsType set;
  set.insert(*new MyClass(10));
  set.insert(*new MyClass(20));
  set.insert(*new MyClass(100));
  auto ite = set.find(100, KeyValCompare());
  ASSERT_TRUE(ite != set.end()); // Fails here

}
```

If I use std::less instead of std::greater, it passes.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

The greater than operator must be change from:

```
friend bool operator >(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
      return lhs.key > rhs.key;
    }
```

to this:

```
friend bool operator >(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
          return lhs.key < rhs.key;
        }
```